# FileInputStream strange behavior if file contains \input

Tags: filenotfoundexception, ioexception, fileinputstream

When I try to open a FileInputStream for a file that contains a line that starts with \input I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/me/??? (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
```

What going on and what's a workaround?

Comment: could you show the code please

Comment: It's simple:

new FileInputStream(fileName)

fails if the file contains a line that starts with "\input" (without the quotes).